# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label') in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, typeerror

```js
//this my sector
sectors:[
  {label: 'bb', key: 0, value: 0}
  {label: 'aa', key: 33, value: 33}
  {...}
]
```

I write code for counting duplicates in an object, but I have a problem in the last mapping section, I get this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label')  in react js

```js
// this is my finalArray that I log 
finalArray:[
  {cs: '44', count: 55}
  {cs: '56', count: 47}
  {cs: '43', count: 41}
  {cs: '27', count: 40}
  {cs: '42', count: 36}
  {cs: '53', count: 35}
  {cs: '34', count: 32}
  {cs: '70', count: 31}
  {cs: '66', count: 22}
  {cs: '54', count: 21}
]

// this is my code 
const prepareSeries = (data, sectors) => {
  let finalArray = [];
  const countsByCs = {};
  data.forEach(({ cs }) => {
    countsByCs[cs] = (countsByCs[cs] || 0) + 1;
  });
  finalArray = Object.entries(countsByCs)
    .map(([cs, count]) => ({ cs, count })) 
    .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
    .slice(0, 10);
  console.log(finalArray);
  return [
    {
      data: finalArray.map((item) => {
        return { name: sectors.filter((sector) => sector.key == item[0])[0].label, y: item[1] };
      }),
    },
  ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code

```
return { name: sectors.filter((sector) => sector.key == item[0]).label, y: item[1] }
```